# Ruby Hash initialised with each_with_object behaving weirdly

Tags: ruby, hash

Initializing Ruby Hash like:

```
keys = [0, 1, 2]
hash = Hash[keys.each_with_object([]).to_a]
```

is behaving weirdly when trying to insert a value into a key.

```
hash[0].push('a')
# will result into following hash:
=> {0=>["a"], 1=>["a"], 2=>["a"]}
```

I am just trying to insert into one key, but it's updating the value of all keys.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Can you tell me what's happening? I just wanted to initialize a hash with keys having value as an array. And it's creating a hash, but later with insertion, it's behaving weirdly and I am not getting the why part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that `each_with_object` is super-weird in itself. That's not how it should be used. And the problem arises **precisely** because you mis-use it.

```
keys.each_with_object([]).to_a
# => [[0, []], [1, []], [2, []]]
```

You see, even though it *looks* like these arrays are separate, it's actually the same array in all three cases. That's why if you push an element into one, it appears in all others.

Here's a better way:

```
h = keys.each_with_object({}) {|key, h| h[key] = []}
# => {0=>[], 1=>[], 2=>[]}
```

Or, say

```
h = keys.zip(Array.new(keys.size) { [] }).to_h
```

Or a number of other ways.

If you don't care about hash having this exact set of keys and simply want **all** keys to have empty array as default value, that's possible too.

```
 h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
```

Comment: That `3` should be `keys.size`

Comment: As always, check `object_id` when you're wondering why you have an army of clones.

Answer (score 0):

All your keys **reference** the same array.

A simplified version that explains the problem:

```
a = []
b = a
a.push('something')
puts a #=> ['something']
puts b #=> ['something']
```

Even though you have two variables (`a` and `b`) there is only one Array **Object**. So any changes to the array *referenced* by variable `a` will change the array *referenced* by variable `b` as well. Because it is the same object.

The long version of what you are trying to achieve would be:

```
keys = [1, 2, 3]
hash = {}
keys.each do |key|
  hash[key] = []
end
```

And a shorter version:

```
[1, 2 ,3].each_with_object({}) do |key, accu|
  accu[key] = []
end
```